# colab.research.google.com - Notebook exceeds size limit

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using the following code:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
page = requests.get("http://portfoliodeagencias.meioemensagem.com.br/anuario/propaganda/agencias/listacompleta")
conteudo_pagina = page.content
string_conteudo_pagina = conteudo_pagina.decode("UTF-8")
lista_de_contato = {}

agencias = re.findall(r'<strong class=\"titu-nome-free\">(.*?)</strong></a></li>\n',str(string_conteudo_pagina))

i=0
while i < 10:
  for nome in agencias:
    if re.search(r'<li><a> <strong class=\"titu-tel-free\">(.*?)</strong>\n',str(string_conteudo_pagina)).start() < re.search(r'<li><a href=\"(.*?)\"><strong',str(string_conteudo_pagina)).start():
      lista_de_contato[nome] = re.findall(r'<li><a> <strong class=\"titu-tel-free\">(.*?)</strong>\n',str(string_conteudo_pagina)),re.findall(r'<li><a href=\"(.*?)\"><strong',str(string_conteudo_pagina))
      string_conteudo_pagina[re.search(r'<li><a href=\"(.*?)\"><strong',str(string_conteudo_pagina)).start():]
      i = i+1
    else:
      lista_de_contato[nome] = re.findall(r'<li><a> <strong class=\"titu-tel-free\">(.*?)</strong>\n',str(string_conteudo_pagina)),'0'
      string_conteudo_pagina[re.search(r'<li><a> <strong class=\"titu-tel-free\">(.*?)</strong>\n',str(string_conteudo_pagina)).start():]
      i = i+1

lista_de_contato
```

I get the following message:

```
Your notebook size is close to the file size limit (19.5M). Large new outputs may be dropped. So far, 22.1M of output have been discarded.
```

Is there a way to make this code better in terms of size limit?

tks

Comment: there are 3.674 keys in this dictionary, I just added the while loop <10 to see if indexing fewer values would make the code run

Answer (score 1):

Your **notebook** exceeded size, not your code.

Your last line, `lista_de_contato`, it is outputting data to your notebook.

THAT makes the notebook big, not your code.

As a suggestion, I would try to limit the display. For instance, if you store the data in a pandas dataframe, the display will be limited automatically for you. I always try to organize data from scraping in pandas dataframes because they are really easy to export and to fiddle around.

Also, if you need, I'm brazilian as well and may help (I'm assuming you're brazilian as well, because you're scraping a brazilian advertising website)

Comment: Thanks, I am Brazilian too. Lets get in contact. What is the best way to reach you. Maybe we can do some projects together!

Comment: (updated my profile so it uses my name. Should be easy to google it)